# ¿Como pasar Type 'Uint8Array' a type 'number' en Angular ts?

Tags: angular, post, conversión-de-tipos, cast, numberformat

Intento usar  el resultado de un post que es un Unit8Array , usarlo como number y no puedo, en otro post que debe enviar number.  Me da error

```
 Type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

¿como puedo hacer el cast? No lo consigo de ninguna forma. 
Gracias.

[image: metodo post con Uint8Array con error]

siguiendo las recomendaciones de un compañero de Stackoverflow que hizo aquí, pongo...

```
onSubmit() : void {    
    this.userLogin=this.myLoginForm.value;
    this.userLogin.id=0;
    console.log("user LOGIN  es => " , this.userLogin);

     this._postLoginService.autentificarUsuario( this.userLogin).subscribe(data=>{

      this.data=new Uint8Array(data);

    console.log ( "TERMINO POST. Mi usuario ID es: ",  data);///camnio
    })
   console.log("tamaño de data :::: " + this.data.length);
    this._postLoginService.datosUsuarioByID( this.data[0] ).subscribe(data=>{
    this.usuario=data;})

   }//onSubmit
```

y por consola me da error:

```
Dentro Servicio de autenficación de usuario   {email: "daniel@gmail.com", password: "daniel123", id: 0}
LoginComponent.html:46 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at LoginComponent.onSubmit (login.component.ts:47)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginComponent.html:46)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:42925
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
View_LoginComponent_0 @ LoginComponent.html:46
proxyClass @ compiler.js:19671
logError @ core.js:45546
handleError @ core.js:6066
dispatchEvent @ core.js:29808
(anonymous) @ core.js:42925
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2668
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:39680
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
LoginComponent.html:46 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 38, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_LoginComponent_0 @ LoginComponent.html:46
proxyClass @ compiler.js:19671
logError @ core.js:45546
handleError @ core.js:6071
dispatchEvent @ core.js:29808
(anonymous) @ core.js:42925
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2668
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:39680
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
UsuarioRegistrado.Service.ts:32 ver que tengo  25
UsuarioRegistrado.Service.ts:38 Usuario inscrito OK 25
login.component.ts:45 TERMINO POST. Mi usuario ID es:  25
```

Continuo sin saber que hago mal. Gracias. Veo que falla al buscar longitud del array.

Comment: Recuerda que estás intentando pasar un conjunto de valores a uno sólo.

Comment: Gracias, la palabra Array debia darme una pista. Pero ahora si pongo this.data[0] me da error "RROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"  ¿Como lo recupero? Perdona, seguro que la pregunta es tonta, pero no se como recuperar la informacion y usarla como deseo. Gracias

Comment: Eso puede ser porque no has inicializado o asignado correctamente el valor **data**, o el valor asignado está vacio.   (veo en tu código/imagen que lo asignas previamente haciendo this.data=data:  debería ser **this.data=new Unit8Array(data)**.  Verifica que contine datos cuando lo asignas la primera vez o cuando quieras acceder a uno de sus elementos.  (usando, por ejemplo: **this.data.length**)

Comment: El comentario anterior lo he puesto porque posiblemente estés utilizando una versión que requiere ese tipo de inicialización del objeto (lo deduzco del error que te ha lanzado).  CITO de la documentación oficial:  "_A partir de ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), los constructores de Uint8Array requieren ser construidos con un operador new. Llamar a un constructor de Uint8Array como una función sin new, lanzará un **TypeError** de ahora en adelante_."

Comment: Uso Angular 8. Mi código por consola termina con el id del usuario que es correctamente validado. En consola sale```` "TERMINO POST. Mi usuario ID es:  25"```` data recoge el número 25.

Answer (score 0):

Al final mi problema era que al ejecutar dos post en cascada, es importante como va. Es decir post1 me devuelve un dato que usa post2. si yo hago post1 y luego post2 no va. Podéis ver código en pregunta. Me dice undefined. tengo que hacer post1 ( post2 ) uno dentro del otro. Me explico mal. Pongo copia mi código.

```
onSubmit() : void {    
    this.userLogin=this.myLoginForm.value;
    this.userLogin.id=0;
    console.log("user LOGIN  es => " , this.userLogin);

     this._postLoginService.autentificarUsuario( this.userLogin).subscribe(data=>{

      this.data=data 

      console.log ( "TERMINO POST. Mi usuario ID es: ",  data);
      console.log("Fuera de post data tiene que salir :::: " + this.data);

    this._postLoginService.datosUsuarioByID( this.data ).subscribe(data=>{
      this.usuario=data;})

    })
```

Y por consola sale

```
ver que tengo  25
UsuarioRegistrado.Service.ts:38 Usuario inscrito OK 25
login.component.ts:45 TERMINO POST. Mi usuario ID es:  25
login.component.ts:46 Fuera de post data tiene que salir :::: 25
UsuarioRegistrado.Service.ts:59 NO ENTRA -------- NO ENTRA   .------ NO ENTRA---- 25urlhttp://localhost:8080/sanitaUned/buscarUsuarioById
UsuarioRegistrado.Service.ts:64 ver que tengo en post de datosUsuariosByID
```

No era tanto un problema de tipo, como de tiempos. Gracias